# Is it possible to get the data for twitter search API version 1.1 using Client Side Scripting

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I'm developing SharePoint Hosted APP in that i need to use java script only. In previous version 1.0 i can get the data using client side scripting but now in the twitter search API version 1.1 they using some authentication.So that we need register in the twitter site and then get consumer key. using this we need to code in server side script and consume the data from the API.

Is it possible to get the data for twitter search API version 1.1 using Client Side Scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The basic idea to use authentication for Twitter API was to make the site secure. If we use client side scripting to fetch data from the twitter website then it serves no purpose to have authentication.

Check out this tutorial which describes how to use the new twitter API.
http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/

This tutorial is a PHP based solution however if you go to the Twitter develeloper site you will find a lot of other libraries in Python, PERL, JAVA, ASP.NET etc. Choose the library of your choice and develop your code...
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries